# NPAPI: is there a way to generate an event to JS?

Tags: javascript, html, npapi

Is there a way to have an NPAPI plugin generate an event on the host page side? i.e. the page that contains the `<embed>` tag instantiating the plugin.

Disclaimer: I am an NPAPI newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way: on the plugin side, expose an "addEventListener" method and have the JS side use this API to register "listeners".

When an event occurs on the plugin side, iterate through the "listeners".

Comment: Hi jldupont, so you create another method called addEventListener and use normal lists to store NPObject* so you can call them later on?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this: [Generating async Javascript events from browser plugin (NPAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931883/generating-async-javascript-events-from-browser-plugin-npapi)