# Browser main thread from the NPAPI plugin

Tags: multithreading, plugins, browser, model, npapi

I am developing an NPAPI plugin and I need to run some code from browser's main thread.

What is the threading model for NPAPI plugins? What is the default thread from which NPAPI executes? How can I run my code from the browser's main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threading model is that browser will call your plugin in the main thread, and you must call `NPN_*` methods from the main thread.

Comment: Wow; I did all the work below and not even a +1 for helping to provide clarification? harsh.

Answer (score 4):

As smorgan said, the threading model of the browser is that any calls to the browser have to occur on the main thread.  There are one or two odd exceptions to this but the support is somewhat inconsistent.

[NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall) was introduced to solve exactly this problem; it accepts a function pointer an a void* for data to be passed into it and will call that function on the main thread.  Of course, there are some tricky things going on here because you aren't guaranteed that your function will be called if you call [NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall) during plugin shutdown due to an inherent race condition.  [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org) does some fairly exotic voodoo to take care of this and prevent memory leaks.

Things thicken a bit more when you start trying to support other browsers besides FireFox; AFAIK FireFox supports this API call in all versions, but at least some versions of Safari (particularly 64 bit) don't support NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall; most interestingly they sometimes seem to support it but you end up with a bad function pointer that crashes when you try to use it. It's possible this has been fixed in a very recent version, I don't know because we long ago changed to using an NSTimer on Mac in order to avoid the problem of not being able to detect correctly whether or not it was supported.  Also Opera on windows has been known to not have support for it. FireBreath uses a message HWND and does PostMessage to make calls on the main thread on windows browsers with no support for it.

I don't know if similar problems exist anywhere on linux; you didn't specify which platform you were concerned about. I haven't heard of any issues on linux, but that may or may not mean anything.

Other questions worth reading on the topic:
[Generating async Javascript events from browser plugin (NPAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931883)
[How to callback plugin thread on Safari 5.1 on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924653)

Good luck